# Multiple Custom Writable formats

Tags: hadoop, writable

I have multiple input sources and I have used Sqoop's codegen tool to generate custom classes for each input source

```
public class SQOOP_REC1 extends SqoopRecord  implements DBWritable, Writable

public class SQOOP_REC2 extends SqoopRecord  implements DBWritable, Writable
```

On the Map side, based on the input source, I create objects of the above 2 classes accordingly.

I have the key as type "Text" and since I have 2 different types of values, I kept the value output type as "Writable".

On the reduce side, I accept the value type as Writable.

```
   public class SkeletonReduce extends Reducer<Text,Writable, Text, Text> {

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Writable> values, Context context) throws     IOException,InterruptedException {

   }
}
```

I also set

```
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Writable.class);
```

During execution, it does not enter the reduce function at all.

Could someone tell me if it possible to do this? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify `Writable` as your output type; it has to be a concrete type. All records need to have the same (concrete) key and value types, in `Mapper`s and `Reducer`s. If you need different types you can create some kind of hybrid `Writable` that contains either an "A" or "B" inside. It's a little ugly but works and is done a lot in Mahout for example.

But I don't know why any of this would make the reducer not run; this is likely something quite separate and not answerable based on this info.

Answer (score 0):

Look into extending GenericWritable for your value type. You need to define the set of classes which are allowed (SQOOP_REC1 and SQOOP_REC2 in your case), and it's not as efficient because it creates new object instances in the readFields method (but you can override this if you have a small set of classes, just have instance variables of both types, and a flag which denotes which one is valid)

- http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/GenericWritable.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured out how to do this. Based on a suggestion give by Doug Cutting himself

http://grokbase.com/t/hadoop/common-user/083gzhd6zd/multiple-output-value-classes

I wrapped the class using ObjectWritable

```
ObjectWritable obj = new ObjectWritable(SQOOP_REC2.class,sqoop_rec2);
```

And then on the Reduce side, I can get the name of the wrapped class and Cast it back to the original class.

```
if(val.getDeclaredClass().getName().equals("SQOOP_REC2")){
                SQOOP_REC2temp = (SQOOP_REC2) val.get();
```

And don't forget

```
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(ObjectWritable.class);
```